# How to show progress Bar when the thread is waiting

Tags: android, progressdialog

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
dialog.show();
    synchronized (this) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Waiting for closed rides to be loaded");
            try {
                wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
```

I have tried using above code for progress bar, how ever the Progress bar is not displayed

Comment: You are immediately calling dismiss progress bar, so its dismissing from activity. Comment that line and check.

Comment: why are doing so ? what is your requirement . There best way to use Asynctask or handler

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `ProgressDialog` and immediately dismissing it because your different thread is on wait not the thread on which `ProgressDialog` is created. It means `dialog.show()` and `dialog.dismiss()` is executed one after another and that's why you cant see the dialog.

Put

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

after

```
wait();
```

Comment: @LakshmiKanth:  Try giving `wait()` a time duration like `wait(5000)`.

Comment: From the other method we are notifying on some condition          synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }

Answer (score -1):

I think this one works for you

```
     final Dialog login = new Dialog(this);
            // Set GUI of login screen
            login.setContentView(R.layout.forgot_password);
            login.setTitle(R.string.Forgot_Password );
            login.setCancelable(true);

            // Init button of login GUI
            Button btnLogin = (Button) login.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            Button btnCancel = (Button) login.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

   TextView tvForgotUsername =  (TextView)login.findViewById(R.id.tvForgotUsername);
            tvForgotUsername.setText(R.string.Forgot_Username);
            etForgot = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
            etForgot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            // Attached listener for login GUI button
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (etForgot.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
   Toast.makeText(LoginScreenActivity.this,"Email will be send to your email address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            login.dismiss();

                }
            });
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    login.dismiss();
                }
            });
            // Make dialog box visible.
            login.show();
```